# Find an item in a list

Tags: c#, list, object, search, recursion

In C#, if I have a list of objects where each list has a list of list items, and each of these list items can be a list of objects (or just a single list item), what is the best way to retrieve a specific list by name?

Each list and list item has a unique name. The type attribute in the `MapLocationListItem` is either "List" or "ListItem".

Here are the classes:

```
public class MapLocationList
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<MapLocationListItem> listItems { get; set;}

    public MapLocationList ()
    {
        listItems = new List<MapLocationListItem> ();
    }
}

public class MapLocationListItem
{
    public string name { get; set;}
    public string type { get; set;}
    public string heading { get; set;}
    public string subheading { get; set;}
    MapLocationList mapLocationList{ get; set;}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to use Linq and specify which item you need to find

Comment: Your model looks a little strange to me, your `MapLocationList` has a list of `MapLocationListItem`'s that has a list of `MapLocationList`s?

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a tree (with two types of nodes) (also assuming you have no cycles, which would make it a graph).  Traversing a tree is a fairly straightforward problem that we can actually solve in the general case with just a handful of lines of code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source
    , Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>(source);
    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var next = stack.Pop();
        yield return next;
        foreach (var child in childrenSelector(next))
            stack.Push(child);
    }
}
```

So, now that we have a `List<MapLocationList>` all we need is to create a function to get all child items of any given node to use our `Traverse` method.  If we only had one type of node we'd just get all child nodes directly.  Since we have two types, we need to use `SelectMany` to get the children of our child nodes:

```
var allNodes = rootNodes.Traverse(mapLocations => 
    mapLocations.listItems.SelectMany(item => item.list));
```

From here we can easily get the first item with a given name:

```
var servyNode = allNodes.FirstOrDefault(node => node.name == "Servy");
```

Answer (score -1):

Find the solution as below, this will find and return the MapLocationListItem otherwise null (if not found)

```
    public class MapLocationList
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<MapLocationListItem> listItems { get; set; }

        public MapLocationList()
        {
            listItems = new List<MapLocationListItem>();
        }

        public MapLocationListItem findByName(string locationName)
        {
            MapLocationListItem findRes = listItems.Where(x => x.name.Equals(locationName)).FirstOrDefault();
            return findRes;
        }
    }

    public class MapLocationListItem
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string heading { get; set; }
        public string subheading { get; set; }
        MapLocationList list { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I believe the asker also wants to recurse through all the contained lists in `MapLocationListItem` as well...

Answer (score -1):

you can use Linq :

```
   var res = from item in listItems
             where item.Name equals "yourentry"
             select item;
```

or simply :

```
MapLocationListItem findRes = listItems.Where(x => x.name.Equals(yourentry)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I believe the asker also wants to recurse through all the contained lists in MapLocationListItem as well..